# Error when using icon function in shiny app

Tags: html, r, shiny, icons

I have an error while using `icon("fa fa-stack-overflow", "fa-2x")` to display stack overflow logo in my Shiny app. The same error also occurs with other icons. However, the icon appears to the application correctly, I just want to get rid of the popup error in the console.

Error message: The name provided ('fa fa-stack-overflow') does not correspond to a known icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `icon("stack-overflow", "fa-2x")` instead.